# Between all the triangles with P=1 find the ones with A max

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

The title is the text of the exercise (A is area, P is perimeter).
I would like to solve it with Lagrange moltiplicators.
I already found a solution with Erone's formula.
But I would like to approach the problem describing the triangles with sine and cosine, this is my idea:
I consider two circumferences with differents radiuses, circumference 1 has radius $\rho_1$ and the circumference 2 $\rho_2$, the radiuses changes and $0<\rho_1, \rho_2<1$.
Now, these two circumferences have the same sine, so I'm describing all the possible triangles (the circumferences are connected by them sines) then $\rho_1\sin\theta=\rho_2\sin\phi$.
Now it's easy to write the heights of the triangles because are equal to the sine (one of them), and for the perimeter (which is the bound) I can write:
$$P=\rho_1\cos\theta+\rho_2\cos\phi+\rho_1+\rho_2=1$$
Also the area is, for example:
$$A=(\rho_1\cos\theta+\rho_2\cos\phi)(\rho_1\sin\theta)$$

Now I can write Lagrange's equation for Lagrange moltiplicators:
$$\mathscr L=A-\lambda P=(\rho_1\cos\theta+\rho_2\cos\phi)(\rho_1\sin\theta)-\lambda(\rho_1\cos\theta+\rho_2\cos\phi+\rho_1+\rho_2-1)$$

But I'm not considering that $0<\rho_1, \rho_2<1$
and it cames out, when I establish $\nabla\mathscr L=0$, that $\rho_1<0$

Is this approach totally didastrous or am I only making mistakes in resolution?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the question?  If $A=1$ then that is the max of $A$.  Did you mean something else?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean that perimeter is one, I'm going to edit the title

Comment: That makes sense.  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592917/simple-proof-that-equilateral-triangles-have-maximum-area) is a related question.  At least one of the answers gives a non-Heron proof.

Comment: The triangle with max area is equilateral. Since the perimeter is $1$ the side is $\dfrac{1}{3}$ and the area is $A=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{36}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sine theorem:
$$abc=8R^3\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}\sin{\gamma}, P=2R(\sin{\alpha}+\sin{\beta}+\sin{\gamma}).$$
The area is:
$$A=\frac{abc}{4R}=\frac{P^2\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}\sin{\gamma}}{2(\sin{\alpha}+\sin{\beta}+\sin{\gamma})^2}\le \frac{P^2(\sin{\alpha}+\sin{\beta}+\sin{\gamma})}{2\cdot 27}\le \frac{P^2}{12\sqrt{3}}.$$
The equality occurs when $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\frac{\pi}{3}$.