# What to do further in Find the maximum area of ellipse....

Tags: analytic-geometry, triangles, conic-sections, area

**$$Question$$**

Find the maximum area of ellipse that can be inscribed in an isosceles triangel of area $A$ and having one axis along the perpendiculur from the vertex of the triangle to the base.

**$$Attempt$$**

So isosceles triangle I made was of coordinates $D(\frac{a} {2},p),B(0,0)$ and $C(a, 0)$.

Now Area of triangle =$A$=$\frac{ap} {2}$ and the point E($\frac{a} {2},0)$ as the feet of perpendicular on BC side by the vertex D. 
 So I assumed that this will be the major axis of that ellipse because the area of the ellipse is $\pi\times a\times b$.

But, from here I am not able to do anything further.

**Any suggestions or hints?**

*Thanks!*

Comment: @symchdmath Please see now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to solve this problem straightforward. However, there is a trick for you.

Let's say we have found a solution and ellipse has axes $a$ and $b$. Let's scale the picture in the direction of axis $b$ by $a/b$ times. Then, ellipse will turn into a circle. Isosceles triangle will turn into some other isosceles triangle. However, the ratio of their areas will remain the same. Then we ask ourselves the question: what isosceles triangle has the largest incircles (in terms of area ratio).

$$
R=\frac{A_{incircle}}{A_{triangle}} = \frac{\pi r^2}{A_{triangle}}=\frac{\pi(2A_{triangle}/P)^2}{A_{triangle}}=4\pi\frac{A_{triangle}}{P^2}.
$$

We used here a formula $A_{triangle}=\frac12 Pr$, that area of triangle is half of perimeter times radius of incircle. So now question is what is the largest area can isosceles triangle have with given perimeter. That is [very well known question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592917/simple-proof-that-equilateral-triangles-have-maximum-area). The answer is equilateral triangle.

So the framework to find a the ellipse with the largest area is the following: you scale your triangle by some value $k$ to make it equilateral, draw an incircle, and then scale everything back.

Comment: Or, is that the area of ellipse =$\frac{(\pi)A} {3\sqrt{3}}$