# Greatest product (Using Calculus)

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

We know that whatever number $n$ may be, we must divide 
it into two equal parts if the product of the parts is to be a maxi-
mum; and the value of that maximum product will always 
be $= 0.25n^2$.

Let the number to be cut 
into two parts be called n. Then if $x$ is one part, the other will be 
$n - x$, and the product will be $x(n - x)$ or $nx - x^2$
• So we write 
$y = nx - x^2$
• Now differentiate and equate to zero;
We get, $n-2x=0$ or $n/2=x$.
 I know it worked for two parts.

Now, my question is, how it would work for proving that the product is max. if these three numbers($m,n,p$) are equal, when sum of these three is constant. we are given three numbers, such that $m+n+p=k$, where $k$ is some constant. $(m,n,p,)$ are positive real numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you correct the question to restriction to positive parts, look up the AM-GM inequality

Comment: But i want to do using calculus.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "natural" numbers? Do you not allow fractions?

Comment: No. I don't need for fractions. I am pretty sure if you do this for me for naturals, i will manage to generalise for fractions.

Comment: @user36956 It is much easier to solve the problem for positive reals than it is for natural numbers. In fact, you solved it for positive reals, but not for natural numbers, since you don't know if $x=\frac n2$ is a natural number.

Comment: Hmm... Sorry, but i am new here. I understand.

Comment: @user36956 Nothing wrong with being new, I am not judging you. I am just trying to help you articulate the answer you want to ask.

Comment: Ohkk... For a moment i felt offended. Yes, i want someone to help me ask coherently. Thanks if you wanted to help! :)

Comment: Oh, via calculus? Sounds interesting! I don't know the answer, I will follow the thread, +1.

Comment: Hmm... Waiting for someone to help using calculus.

Comment: You recieved 5 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove AM-GM with calculus (and induction).

Let's prove that, given $x_1,\dots,x_k>0$, we have
$$
\sqrt[k]{x_1x_2\dotsm x_k\mathstrut}\le \frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k}{k}
$$
For simplicity, denote by $\gamma(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ the left-hand side and by $\alpha(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k)$ the right-hand side. Thus we want to prove
$$
(\text{AM-GM})_k\qquad \gamma(x_1,\dots,x_k)\le\alpha(x_1,\dots,x_k)
$$

The base case of induction, $k=1$, is obvious. Suppose we know the statement for $k$ and we're given $k+1$ positive numbers $x_1,\dots,x_k,x$; we want to prove that
$$
\gamma(x_1,\dots,x_k,x)\le\alpha(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k,x)
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
(k+1)^{k+1}\gamma(x_1,\dots,x_k,x)^{k+1}\le\alpha(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k,x)^{k+1}
$$
Let's write $P=(x_1\dotsm x_k)^{1/k}$ and $S=x_1+\dots+x_k$ so the statement to be proved becomes
$$
(k+1)^{k+1}P^kx\le(S+x)^{k+1}
$$
under the induction hypothesis that $kP\le S$. Consider the function
$$
f(x)=(S+x)^{k+1}-(k+1)^{k+1}P^kx
$$
Then $f'(x)=(k+1)(S+x)^k-(k+1)^{k+1}P^k$, which vanishes for $S+x=(k+1)P$, that is, $x=(k+1)P-S$. Note that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=S^{k+1}>0,\qquad \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty
$$
If $(k+1)P-S\le0$, the function is increasing and so the inequality is proved. Suppose $(k+1)P-S>0$. Then $f$ has an absolute minimum at $(k+1)P-S$ and
\begin{align}
f((k+1)P-S)
&=(k+1)^{k+1}P^{k+1}-(k+1)^{k+1}P^k(kP+P-S)\\[4px]
&=(k+1)^{k+1}P^k\bigl(P-kP-P+S\bigr)\\[4px]
&=(k+1)^{k+1}P^k(S-kP)\ge0
\end{align}
Thus the inequality is proved in every case.

Notice also that the minimum is zero *if and only if* $S=kP$. Thus, again by induction, we prove that equality in AM-GM$_k$ is attained only when $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_k$.

With the inequality at hand, assume $x_1+\dots+x_k=n$. Then
$$
x_1x_2\dotsm x_k\le(n/k)^k
$$
On the other hand, for $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_k$, the two terms are equal and equality only holds in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \ge 0$ are nonnegative reals, subject to the constraint $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = k$.  We reason by induction that the maximum value of the product $x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n$ is attained when $x_1 = x_2 = \ldots = x_n = k/n$.

First, the case where $n = 2$ was already addressed.  So in the case $n = 3$, suppose $x_3$ is fixed, hence the maximum occurs when $x_1 = x_2 = (k - x_3)/2$ and the resulting product is $x_1 x_2 x_3 = (k - x_3)^2 x_3/2$.  Now if $x_3$ is allowed to take on different values in $[0,k]$, the fact that the product is maximized when $x_1 = x_2$ remains true, so we can argue that as a function of $x_3$, the product is maximized for some critical point of this function, namely $$0 = \frac{d}{dx_3}\left[\frac{(k - x_3)^2 x_3}{2}\right] = (k - x_3)x_3 + \frac{(k - x_3)^2}{2}.$$  Solving the quadratic results in $x_3 = k$ (which obviously corresponds to a minimum) and $x_3 = k/3$.  A convexity argument indicates this yields the desired maximum, and $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = k/3$.

The above is naturally extensible.  For suppose that we have established that the product is maximized on $n$ variables when all are equal to $k/n$.  Then for $n+1$ variables, consider $x_{n+1}$ fixed, so the product is $$x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n x_{n+1} = \frac{(k-x_{n+1})^n x_{n+1}}{n}.$$  Searching for the critical point with respect to $x_{n+1} \in [0,k]$ yields $x_{n+1} = k/(n+1)$, hence $x_1 = x_2 = \ldots = x_{n+1} = k/(n+1)$ and this completes the induction step.

---

Now, if $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are nonnegative **integers**, the above reasoning does not work because we cannot compute critical points to obtain extrema.  Instead, we reason more simply.  Suppose $x_1 + \cdots + x_n = k$.  Then adding $1$ and subtracting $1$ from $x_i$ and $x_j$ respectively, for $i < j$ (without loss of generality), yields the same sum, but the product becomes $x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n$ to $x_1 \ldots (x_i + 1) \ldots (x_j - 1) \ldots x_n$.  If we take the ratio, we find this is $$\frac{(x_i + 1)(x_j - 1)}{x_i x_j} = \frac{x_i x_j - x_i + x_j - 1}{x_i x_j} = 1 - \frac{1}{x_j} + \frac{1}{x_i} - \frac{1}{x_i x_j}.$$  So if $x_i = x_j - 1$, this ratio equals $1$, and the value of the product remains unchanged.  From this, we can see that if $x_i \ge x_j$, then incrementing $x_i$ by $1$ and decrementing $x_j$ by $1$ will decrease the product, and if $x_i < x_j - 1$, it will increase the product.  This is irrespective of the values of the other factors in the product.

Hence, if there exists $i \ne j$ such that $x_i < x_j - 1$, repeatedly incrementing $x_i$ and decrementing $x_j$ so that $|x_i - x_j| \le 1$ will increase the value of the product.  Again without loss of generality, order the terms in nondecreasing sequence, so that $x_i \le x_j$ for all $i < j$.  Then we can see that we must have $|x_n - x_1| \le 1$, which implies that there is a $m$ such that $x_1 = \ldots = x_m$, and $x_{m+1} = \ldots = x_n = x_m + 1$, or $$mx_1 + (n-m)(x_1+1) = (n-m) + nx_1 = k.$$  Since all of these variables are nonnegative integers, we require $n$ to divide $k+m$.  Since $1 \le m \le n$, such a choice of $m$ is unique as there is only one representative of the equivalence class of integers modulo $n$ that is the additive inverse of $k$, namely $m \equiv -k \pmod n$.  As this choice is unique, the corresponding product must be the maximum attainable over the nonnegative integers.

An example of this maximization for $n = 7$, $k = 45$:  we select $m \in \{1, \ldots, 7\}$ such that $45+m$ is divisible by $7$.  This of course is $m = 4$, hence $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4$ and $x_5 = x_6 = x_7 = x_1 + 1$.  We must have $7x_1 + 3 = 45$, or $x_1 = 6$, and the maximum product is $6^4 7^3$.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go about your problem is the AM-GM inequality, which tells you that, for any set of positive real numbers $x_1,\dots, x_n$, the inequality

$$\frac{x_1+\cdots +x_n}{n}\geq \sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n}$$

is true.

In your case, we know that $x_1+\cdots + x_n=k$, which means that $\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n}\leq \frac{k}{n}$, and therefore $x_1\cdots x_n \leq \frac{k^n}{n^n}, is always true.

Selecting $x_i=\frac{k}{n}$ also means that

$$x_1\cdots x_n = \frac{k^n}{n^n}$$

which means that $\frac{k^n}{n^n}$ is the maximum of the expression $x_1\cdots x_n$ under the conditions $x_1,\dots x_n\geq 0$ and $x_1+\cdots + x_n = k$.

Comment: Yet i haven't learnt this inequality. Sorry, but i only know what is AP, but none of the above. It is inconvenient for me to leave calculus learning (from calculus made easy by Thompson), even for some time. Please help me to do it using calculus.

Comment: @user36956 You are trying to run when you can barely walk. What you are presenting is a multivariate minimization problem, and the *general* solution for solving those is the Lagrange Multiplier method, a method that requires much more pre-existing knowledge. I don't see how it would be wise to teach Lagrange multipliers to people who haven't yet covered the AM-GM inequality...

Comment: Do you mean to say that for two numbers, i can prove using my existing knowledge, but for three numbers, my knowledge is insufficient?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/592917/669752

Comment: Please look for carl's answer in the above link. I am able to relate that to my question. But how he is allowed to do the derivative like this. Taking one variable as constant and other as variable and next time taking the same variable as constant, and the constant as variable to obtain two equations in terms of 'a' & 'b'.

Comment: @user36956 Yes, exactly. For two numbers, the problem is an intro-to-calculus level problem. For more than two, you need multivariate calculus (or the AM-GM inequality) to solve it. The derivatives in the linked answer, where some variables are "constants", is exactly that: derivatives of multivariate functions.

Comment: under what topic i will be learning multivariable calculus then? I am asking because i am eager to know whether till the end of my book i 'll be able to deal with multivariable calculus problems or not!

Comment: @user36956 Depends on the book. Where I studied, our first year of calculus was all single-variable calculus, and then the entire second year of calculus was multivariate calculus. It's a big subject, after all.

Comment: Oh! I think i need to cover a long distance then. I am just in class 11 now.:) Well, i am learning it from 'Calculus Made Easy' by Thompson!

Answer (score 0):

Given two numbers $y\geq x>0$ with sum $n$ you can write them as
$$x={n\over2}-h,\quad y={n\over2}+h$$
with some $h\geq0$. It follows that
$$xy={n^2\over4}-h^2<{n^2\over4}\qquad(h>0)\ .$$
This shows that $x=y={n\over2}$ gives the maximal product.

If we are given $r$ numbers $x_i>0$ $(1\leq i\leq r)$ with sum $n$, and two of them are unequal, say $x_1<x_2$, then we can enlarge the product $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i$ by replacing $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $x_1'=x_2'={x_1+x_2\over2}$. Doing this we have not alered the sum $n$ of all ixes. If you accept without proof that a maximal product existsthis maximal product must have all ixes equal, namely $x_i={n\over r}$ $(1\leq i\leq r)$.