# Maximum area of a right-angled triangle with a fixed perimeter - can it be done without calculus?

Tags: geometry

The area, $A$, of a right-angled triangle with fixed perimeter $P$ will be maximised when the triangle is isosceles (i.e. is a multiple of the $1, 1, \sqrt{2}$ right-angled triangle). I know how to prove this using calculus, but I am interested to know whether there is an alternative proof that doesn't need advanced techniques. In particular, [Simple proof that equilateral triangles have maximum area](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592917/simple-proof-that-equilateral-triangles-have-maximum-area) shows that a proof without calculus is possible in the general case (to show that the area of any triangle with fixed perimeter will be maximum when the triangle is equilateral), so I think a simple proof should also be possible in the right-angled case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a , b , c be the sides of the right angle triangle right angle at C.
$$ \therefore a^2+b^2=c^2 \,,where\,a+b+c=p\, ,\,perimeter\, of \,triangle$$
Using $AM\ge GM$ between $a^2,b^2$ we get
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \ge (ab)$$
$$\therefore ab\le \frac{c^2}{2}$$
Hence maximum area is $A=\frac{1}{2}ab=\frac{c^2}{4}$
$$ $$ AM = GM holds when $a=b$ ttherfore $c=\sqrt{2}a$ 
Hence sides are $a,a,\sqrt{2}a$ hence $a=(\frac{p}{2}(2-\sqrt{2}))$ where p is constant perimeter.

Comment: Thanks very much!